# How to fix App's Compatibility

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, compatibility

Im so confuse and tired about my app compatibility
My problem is :

I got an app on Appstore . But my app compatibility is iOS 8.4 that so many people can't download my app. Almost people not often update their device so that their device is low version than iOS 8.4 What should i do now ?

Can i make my app compatibility down to older version ?
Or In Upload App Progress ,does somewhere i must be notice to choose the compatibility of my app ?

How to know about the app compatibility before archive app . I look up for many app in App Store they are iOS 7.0 or older . Why my app is up to iOS 8.4 ? So confuse

Best Regard

Answer (score 1):

Maybe **Deployment Target** of your app is "8.4". If you set lower version (ex. 7.0), many users can download your app.

[image]